# Звук [й] в транскрипции

Tags: транскрипция, фонетика

Вопрос из сборника: в каком слове есть звук [j']? Варианты ответа: 1) познакомьте; 2) съёмки; 3) восемьдесят; 4) почтальон. Транскрипции, по-моему, такие: [пъзн^ком'т'ь], [сj'омк'ь], [вос'ьм'д'ис'ьт], [пъч'т^л'j'он] (мы же говорим *почтальён*, а не *почталён*, так?).

Что выбрать?) Или у меня есть ошибки (если есть, объясните, пожалуйста, их), из-за которых путаница?

Дополнительный вопрос: почему у согласных, которые всегда мягкие ([й], [ч], [щ]), в транскрипции ставится апостроф?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А что за сборник-то?! Может, его автор не знает, что почтальон с йотом произносится?!

В отношении второго вопроса. Так принято. Но отнюдь не всегда, есть разные системы транскрипции. Но там, где апостроф ставят, делают это для точности. Потому, что все "всегда мягкие" согласные  в принципе можно произнести и как твердые. Например в слове "додж"  - последний согласный очень даже близок к "твердому Ч".

Comment: Сборник огэшный (гиашный) С. Львовой. У нее в начале даны пояснения, что йот возникает только из букв е, ё, ю, я, стоящих после гласных, мягкого и твердого знака и в начале слова. Хотя я находил такие случаи, когда йот появлялся, к примеру, с [и]. Не знаю, что с ним не так.

Comment: Выкиньте вы его. Да, перед "и" вполне может возникать йот, во всяком случае сейчас это более или менее общепринятая точка зрения. Но. видимо, автор настолько увлекся усеченным школьным "правилом", что запутал и сам себя, и других. В отношении же йота из О должна быть оговорка, что в осеовном правиле речь идет об исконно русских словах, об этом в школе обычно "забывают" сообщить.

Comment: Я бы с удовольствием сжег его. Однако, к сожалению, возможно, это же будет на экзамене...

Comment: Ну тут я не силен, школьные дела для меня - вещь в себе. Подождите, здесь есть практикующие и практиковавшие преподаватели, они должны быть в курсе, как из таких коллизий выходить. Но по мне очевидно, что если ответ должен содержать только одно слово, то пожертвовать надо почтальоном. Вряд ли кто-то может предположить, что в "съемке" нет йота.

Comment: Следуя школьному правилу, да, *почталён* вылетает.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых,интересно, за какой год у Вас сборник Львовой. Фонетики давно в ОГЭ нет, в ЕГЭ тоже. Посмотрите спецификацию в ФИПИ:http://www.fipi.ru/oge-i-gve-9/demoversii-specifikacii-kodifikatory

Во-вторых, в "почтальон" нет звука [j], как нет и йотированных букв , это же иностранное слово.

В-третьих,в школе тоже не ставят мягкость после всегда мягких согласных, только в начальной школе, чтобы приучить малышей, чтоб они запомнили. Так что я бы не советовала пользоваться данным сборником, возьмите Сенину за 2016 или решайте на сайтах "Решу ОГЭ", "По уши в ОГЭ",в открытых заданиях  на ФИПИ

В общем, я считаю это задание некорректным в ОГЭ. Может быть, имели в виду, что там не йот, а "и краткое", как в "май"? Но сейчас вроде бы "и краткое" ушло из терминов.В общем-то, автор же дал пояснение, что звук "йот" только в йотированных буквах.

Но если не говорить о школе, фонема - j. по правилам русской фонетики, в заимствованниых словах -  например, из французского (бульон), испанского (синьор) - в позиции после согласной  передается буквами ьо.

Об этом можно прочитать: http://bibl.tikva.ru/base/B952/B952Part12-59.php

В русских словах для передачи сочетания "йот + гласный" после согласных букв всегда используются йотированные буквы (при этом после согласного ставятся разделительные ъ или ь): объём, подъём; в некоторых же типах заимствованных слов после согласных для передачи сочетания "йот + /о/" иногда пишется ьо: батальон, карманьола, котильон, медальон, миньон, павильон, почтальон, шиньон и т.п. Буква о получает при таком употреблении особое звуковое значение: /йо/. В русских словах буква о такого значения не имеет, и тем не менее подобные заимствованные слова читаются русскими правильно потому, что во всех русских словах, где после буквы ь следует гласная буква, перед гласной буквой непременно произносится йот: келья, певунья, лью, зелье, жилье и т.п. Буква ь перед гласной предупреждает о йоте. Заимствованные слова с сочетанием букв ьо становятся в этот же ряд.

В XIX в. писали почтальйон, батальйон. Так начал писать Н.М. Карамзин. (Еще ранее писали почталiон, баталiон, миллiон.) Появлявшиеся уже тогда написания типа батальон считались неправильными. Я.К. Грот писал: "...никак нельзя одобрить начертаний батальон, мильон... слова в таком начертании могут быть прочитаны не иначе, как если бы было написано: баталён, милён. Для проверки стоит только перенести слог он в другую строку; тогда придется читать: баталь-он и проч. Если б мильон читалось так же, как мильйон, то вместо льём, житьём можно было бы писать льом, житьом. Еще виднее будет несообразность начертания мильон, если вместо о возьмем а и напишем таким образом, например, слова: брильант, сафьан, семьа, платьа вм. брильянт, сафьян, семья.

Но в современном письме "неправильности" закрепились, а вот что слышится - j или й, учёные так и не договорились.
http://coollib.com/b/262438/read

Comment: 1. ОГЭ 2017. Русский язык: сборник заданий 9 класс С. И. Львовой. Москва, Эксмо, 2016.

Comment: 2. Рассмотрим слово *Минюст*. Есть ли там йот? По школьному правилу - нет, потому что йотованный [ю] стоит после согласного [н]. Напишем транскрипцию, следуя ему (правилу): [м' и н' у с т]. А теперь давайте прочитаем написанное: *минюст* (ср. пюре [п' у], утюг [т' у], нюхать [н' у]). Ведь [н' у] = [н' у], так? Тот же *ню* в *Минюсте* и *нюхать*? Ответ очевиден. Поправьте меня, если что-то не так. P. S. А что не так с иностранными словами и йотом?

Comment: 3. Странно, но в моей и в средней, и в старшей принято ставить. Благодарю за рекомендации!

Comment: *Во-вторых, в "почтальон" нет йота* А вот Аванесов так не считает  http://slovarina.ru/russkie/slovari/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988_0431.htm  Да ладно бы только он... С детства помню, что ***почтальон, медальон, бульон*** - все произносятся [льён], т. е. именно с йотом. Да и язык такого  не выдержит, чтоб без йота.

Comment: @Aer *Рассмотрим слово Минюст*. Это другое. На аббревиатуры и сокращения школьные правила заведомо не распространяются. А слов таких - вагон и маленькая тележка. Впрочем, Лопатин с комиссией предлагал в своё время и тут использовать разделитель, только не мягкий знак, а твердый.

Comment: @behemothus Заведомо? Не думаю. Во всяком случае ни в одном известном мне школьном учебнике такой оговорки не было. Я (очень) согласен с Владимиром Владимировичем: ну что это за инязы, минюсты и хозучеты?..

Comment: Произносится - то мягко,но скорее льйон, а не льён - речь о фонемах, а не о звуках, а в школе, Вы правы, упрощённо дают, поэтому и даётся справка, что йот только в йотированных буквах прячется.

Comment: @Людмила Если я не ошибаюсь, й = j, так? Вопрос чисто графический, как ер и шва, к примеру.

Comment: Не всегда.Й-полугласный, его поют: май-й-й, j - согласный. Фонема одна, звуки разные.

Comment: @Людмила *Произносится - то мягко,но скорее льйон, а не льён* - **секундочку, а в чем разница?** Хоть на фонемах, хоть на звуках (не на аллофонах только). Теоретически - да, О в позиции после мягкого согласного имеет слабый призвук "и", поэтому можно (теоретически!) говорить о сочетании звуков Й+О, которое не Ё, но  йот-то по определению всегда мягкий. Так что []о] это Ё и наоборот, как ни посмотри.

Comment: @Людмила, а, кажется понял, о чем вы... Вы хотите сказать, что в "почтальон" нет йота вообще, а "льон" - это "лион" с очень кратким И (*наподобие того, что возникает иногда на стыке слов типа "кратки**й** **о**черк")? Если так, то не согласен. Да, там не Ё, конечно. Но так "почтальон" если и произносили, то очень давно. Сейчас я там слышу полноценное Ё.